# Can adb backup media?

Tags: adb, backup, media-files

Some apps use media stored on the phone (audiobooks, movies, epub, ..) Can `adb backup` backup the media too?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those files you mention are stored in the shared storage that is also visible when the device is connected via USB to a PC, then yes adb can backup those files but by default it ignores them (`by default option` -noshared` is active).

Executing `adb -shared` will create the backup file `backup.ab` containing all the files that are stored within `/sdcard` respectively `/storage/emulated/0` excluding the `Android` folder where app-specific files are located (tested on Android 9).

You can also just add the `-shared` option to an existing `adb backup` command.

BTW: You can still see the `adb backup` comand-line help with all available options which is no longer shown by recent adb versions by executing `adb shell bu help`:

```
 backup [-f FILE] [-apk|-noapk] [-obb|-noobb] [-shared|-noshared] [-all]
        [-system|-nosystem] [-keyvalue|-nokeyvalue] [PACKAGE...]
     write an archive of the device's data to FILE [default=backup.adb]
     package list optional if -all/-shared are supplied
     -apk/-noapk: do/don't back up .apk files (default -noapk)
     -obb/-noobb: do/don't back up .obb files (default -noobb)
     -shared|-noshared: do/don't back up shared storage (default -noshared)
     -all: back up all installed applications
     -system|-nosystem: include system apps in -all (default -system)
     -keyvalue|-nokeyvalue: include apps that perform key/value backups.
         (default -nokeyvalue)
 restore FILE             restore device contents from FILE
```